# How Use table variable in where condition of Update statement

Tags: sql-server

Here is My Query:

```
Declare @ParentIDMap Table (AccTypeID BigInt, FullNo nvarchar(50), Branch BigInt, Code Varchar, ID BigInt)

Insert  @ParentIDMap (AccTypeID, Branch, FullNo, Code)
    Values  (1, 5, '01111', 2),
            -- Some other rows
            (8, 5, '04121', 2)

Update  @ParentIDMap
    Set ID =  Book.ID
    From    Accounting.ACNT.Book
    Where   Book.FullNo = @ParentIDMap.FullNo + @ParentIDMap.Code
```

The Error: **Must declare the scalar variable '@ParentIDMap'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to reference `@ParentIdMap` in the `FROM` clause in order to be able to update (SqlServer differs from other RDBMS in this way). You can also switch to a join:

```
Update  p
    Set p.ID =  Book.ID
    From    Accounting.ACNT.Book 
      INNER JOIN @ParentIDMap p
      ON Book.FullNo = p.FullNo + p.Code;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4143f/2)